# Start an offline ClickOnce Application and wait for Exit

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, clickonce

I have deployed a ClickOnce Windows Forms application (App A)

Another application (App B) starts App A with a filename as parameter.
I do this with this Code

```
var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs);
var location = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}",
    basePath, "MyCompany", "MyProduct", "MyApp.appref-ms");

var fileName = @"c:\temp\somefile.ext";
var uri = new Uri(fileName).ToString();

Process.Start(location, uri);
```

App A grabs the file name from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]` and show the  content.

This works like a charm. However, now I want App B to wait for App A to exit.
But a call to `Process.WaitForExit()` returns instantly.

Is there a way to open a ClickOnce App and wait for it to exit? I can, if necessary, change the way the app is opend but the requirement is that I need to run the app as a ClickOnce app (I know that somewhere in my user profile `AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\` folder the exe exists and can be started directly but If I do that `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` is `false` and `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment` is null. In that I loose the ClickOnce Update Capabilities).

Comment: I think this is the correct behavior. If you're calling the ClickOnce "executable", this will check for updates. But this behavior - as far as I know - is located inside the generated bootstrapper. Which then will call the real executable. I would like to take a look into this behavior later. An idea: Grab the "real" process and wait for it to exit?

Comment: @Herdo - That is easy to achive with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;` and would work. However my app is designed to be called from another app and will not be started directly. If I would do this I would lose the self update feature, the main reason for using click once for this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion would be to use [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in App A, and let App B check and wait for it. This is the cleanest way from my point of view.

App A does this when starts:

```
    private static Mutex mutex;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // if you want your app to be limited to a single instance
        // across ALL SESSIONS (multiple users & terminal services), then use the following line instead:
        // string mutexName = string.Format("Global\\{0}", ProgramInfo.AssemblyGuid);
        var mutexName = string.Format("Local\\{0}", SOME_SHARED_GUID);
        mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out singleInstance);

        if (singleInstance == false)
        {

           // that means your app has more than one instance running
           // you need to decide what to do here.
        }

        // rest of initialization code

        Application.Run();

        // release the mutex so App B can continue
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

and App B just waits for the mutex to be released:

```
Process.Start(location, uri);
Thread.Sleep(5000);  // give it 5 seconds or so to check for updates and start
var mutexName = string.Format("Local\\{0}", SOME_SHARED_GUID);
mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName);
mutex.WaitOne();
```

Comment: That seems to be a good solution, I could use `new FileInfo(fileName).FullName` as the mutex name. That would allow me to start multiple App A instances from mutliple App B instances. Even if App A crashes this would not be a problem since I alread implemented a `Waiting for App A... Cancel` dialog in App B

Comment: I guess this solution can't apply when the clickonce application is not developed by myself?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that starting the appref-ms process does not actually start the application it starts the deployment manifest, which then launches the application itself, so the process you are starting exits straight away.

You can add a check to see when you application has started if you know the name (which I assume you do) like this:

```
string myAppName = "YourAppName";
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
int newProcessId = 0;
List<int> runningProcessIds = new List<int>();

//find all the running processes and record their Ids
foreach (void proc_loopVariable in Process.GetProcessesByName(myAppName)) {
    proc = proc_loopVariable;
    runningProcessIds.Add(proc.Id);
}

//start the new process
Process.Start(location);

//wait for the new application to be started
while (!(Process.GetProcessesByName(myAppName).Count != runningProcessIds.Count)) {
    //timeout if we have not seen the application start
    if ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds > 30)
        break; 
}

//loop through all the running processes again to find the id of the one that has just started
foreach (void proc_loopVariable in Process.GetProcessesByName(myAppName)) {
    proc = proc_loopVariable;
    if (!runningProcessIds.Contains(proc.Id)) {
        newProcessId = proc.Id;
        break; 
    }
}

//wait for the application to finish
Process.GetProcessById(newProcessId).WaitForExit();

Debug.WriteLine("Finished");
```

Comment: You're right, I shortend the example code, it should read `var process = Process.Start(location, uri); process.WaitForExit();` The problem is ClickOnce related since I don't start an exe but a `appref-ms` document and `process.HasExited` is true. The same code with an exe would really wait for the process to exit.

Comment: This could work but I also had to find the specific instance off MyApp since it can run multiple times. I could make a call to `GetProcessByName` before and after running `Process.Start(...)` and figure out which one is new or use `Process.StartTime` to find the right instance.

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer to include how this can be accomplished