# C# Process.Start - how to enforce WaitForExit

Tags: c#, process, clickonce, waitforexit

I have a console app that calls other console apps.

I am using the following link for howto: https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/

I cannot instantiate Process and use that as I get the error message "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

I can call the apps using static version of Process e.g.

```
Process.Start(shortcutPath, arguments);
```

or

```
Process.Start(shortcutPath, arguments).WaitForExit();
```

However, I cannot get the Process to WaitForExit - one app is called and after a while, before the first app completes, the second one is called - which is a problem as it depends on the first app to complete.

Any suggestions on how to get Static version of Process to wait for exit (alt. how to instantiate Process and be able to call clickonce deployed apps?)

Comment: Your variable is called `shortcutPath`. Are you starting a shortcut (`.lnk` file), or an executable (`.exe` file)?

Comment: When you deploy clickonce apps, you end up with a ref that points to whereever MS deploys your actual exe.  I'm calling the this appref.

It will look something like: C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\xxx\xxx\xxx.appref-ms

Comment: I can go and search out these exe's and do the normal process.start thing, but then everytime I redeploy the called apps I have to update the file path in the calling app and redeploy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after bashing my head against a wall for the best part of a day, I found this... [Start an offline ClickOnce Application and wait for Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555768/start-an-offline-clickonce-application-and-wait-for-exit)

Used the mutex option.  Fek me Microsoft, you've take something that used to be really simple and made a real horse's ass out of it.

I was just about to scrap my called exe's and create one monster - was feeling ill at the thought.

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start Method (String, String) has a return value of System.Diagnostics.Process

Which is according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is:

A new Process that is associated with the process resource, or null if no process resource is started. Note that a new process that’s started alongside already running instances of the same process will be independent from the others. In addition, Start may return a non-null Process with its HasExited property already set to true. In this case, the started process may have activated an existing instance of itself and then exited.

So I would check whether process.HasExited is true before calling WaitForExit

```
var process = Process.Start(shortcutPath, arguments);
if (process != null && process.HasExited != true)
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
else
{
    // Process is null or have exited
}
```

Comment: You can call WaitForExit on a process that has already exited. If you couldn't, this code would introduce a race condition.

Comment: foobar - tried this.  It doesn't make any difference - processing just carries on to next call.  If I step through the code and try and see what value the process var has, I get "BasePriority = 'process.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'".  Although the code is in  a try/catch block this does not fire an exception...

Comment: Note: even tho investigating the process var raises an error, the exe called is running with no probs.

Comment: @DaveTapson - Visual Studio may be showing an exception when you attempt to examine a property when its not yet set. For example when I start process, and it's running I see that ExitCode = 'process.ExitCode' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' in this case because process is still running.

Comment: It should be set if the called exe is already running?  I also tried putting a Thread.Sleep(5000) in to give it time to catch up but made no diffs.